# Akka.Net not executing await continuation in PostStop

Tags: c#, akka, akka.net

My actor interacts with a non-Akka thing that has an async disposal. This disposal can take 5-10 seconds. I do this in PostStop() like so:

```cs
protected override void PostStop()
{
    async Task DisposeThing()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Before Delay");
        await Task.Delay(10000); // This would be the actual call to dispose the thing
        Debug.WriteLine("After Delay");
    };

    ActorTaskScheduler.RunTask(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Before DisposeThing");
            await DisposeThing();
            Debug.WriteLine("After DisposeThing");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"An exception occured: {ex}");
        }
        finally
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("actor done disposing.");
        }
    });
    base.PostStop();
}
```

[Full gist here](https://gist.github.com/asik/68d8a25d23304eee71c11256388671da).

The parent does `_childActor.Tell(PoisonPill.Instance)`. I also tried `_childActor.GracefulStop` with a large enough timeout.

In both cases, this prints:

```
Before DisposeThing
Before Delay
```

And that's it, the rest is never executed. Not even the finally executes (which I guess breaks C#? `using` doesn't work anymore, for instance).

Silently dropping await continuations (including finallys) could lead to some really tricky-to-understand bugs, so this leaves me with two questions:

1. when does Akka decide to simply drop an ongoing async function, is there a consistent model to be understood?
2. how should I write this in a way that is guaranteed to execute and not terminate the actor before disposal is done?

**Update:**
After sleeping on this I think I understand what's going on. Keep in mind that is mostly conjecture from someone that's been looking at Akka.Net for the past 2 days (e.g. [this thread](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/3259#issuecomment-356020345)), and I post this because no one has answered yet.

The way Akka.Net implements async continuations is by having the actor executing the async function send `ActorTaskSchedulerMessage`s to itself. This message points to the remaining work to be done after an `await` returns, and when the actor gets to process that message, it'll execute the continuation, up until the next `await` (or the end of the function if there no other `await`).

When you tell an actor to stop with a `PoisonPill` for instance, once that message is processed, no further messages are processed for that actor. This is fine when those messages are user-defined. However, this ends up also silently dropping any async continuations since they're also implemented as actor messages.

Indeed when running a program using the above actor, we can see this in the console:

> [INFO][2022-01-11 2:59:43 PM][Thread 0004][akka://ActorSystem/user/$a/$a] Message [ActorTaskSchedulerMessage] from [akka://ActorSystem/user/$a/$a#132636847] to [akka://ActorSystem/user/$a/$a#132636847] was not delivered. [2](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/3259#issuecomment-356020345) dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior then [akka://ActorSystem/user/$a/$a#132636847] may have terminated unexpectedly. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.

If this understanding is correct, this makes async extremely unreliable inside functions passed to `ReceiveAsync`, `ActorTaskScheduler.RunTask` etc. as you cannot ever assume anything after an `await` will get to execute, including exception handlers, cleanup code inside `finally`s, using statement disposal, etc. Actors can be <s>killed</s> stopped at any time.

I suppose then that since language primitives lose their meaning, what you need to do is wrap your Task-returning functions inside their own little actors and rely on Akka semantics rather than language semantics.

Comment: Actors are only killed under two sets of circumstances:

1. When the `ActorSystem` is terminating or
2. When you explicitly chose to terminate an actor.

Actors aren't arbitrarily killed for any reason. They live forever by default. Just like how an `await` that isn't complete can't stop a .NET process from being shut down the same holds true for an actor. Thousands of developers use `await` without any issues in Akka.NET - it's not "unreliable."

Comment: A member of my team is working on an answer to your question on how to structure it so you can accomplish your goal robustly, however.

Comment: @Aaronontheweb thank you for answering. I should have said "stopped" instead of "killed", e.g. Context.Stop, PoisonPill, an unhandled exception... In the case of `Context.Stop` for instance, no further messages are processed, which seems to drop async continuations scheduled after it. Anyway, I'll read the answer with interest. 
Btw I've asked this in a slightly different way on github https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/discussions/5499 .

Comment: Worth noting: a `PoisonPill` will never cause an actor to terminate before it has finished processing its most recent `async` state machine - this is because the `PoisonPill` passes through the `/user` mailbox, not the `/system` one (which `Context.Stop` uses). This guarantees that all user-defined messages received prior to the `PoisonPill` are processed.

Comment: BTW, I will take a look at your discussion issue too!

Comment: So let's say we're in the middle of a `ReceiveAsync` handler, and we get `PoisonPill`, that entire handler is allowed to finish, even if there's e.g. a loop with an await in it which will keep scheduling continuations for a while after `PoisonPill` is received? These continuations will be given priority over the `PoisonPill` since we're still processing a message received before `PoisonPill` was received?

Answer (score 1):

You captured what the issue was.

This is one solution I came up with:

```
using Akka.Actor;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static Akka.NET_StackOverflow_Questions_tryout.Questions._70655287.ChildActor;

namespace Akka.NET_StackOverflow_Questions_tryout.Questions._70655287
{
    public class ParentActor:ReceiveActor
    {
        private readonly IActorRef _child;
        public ParentActor()
        {
            _child = Context.ActorOf(ChildActor.Prop());
            Context.Watch(_child);
            
            Receive<ShutDown>(s =>
            {
                _child.Forward(s);
            });
            Receive<Terminated>(t => {
                var tt = t;
            });  
        }
        public static Props Prop()
        {
            return Props.Create(() => new ParentActor());
        }
    }


    public class ChildActor : ReceiveActor
    {
        public ChildActor()
        {
            ReceiveAsync<ShutDown>(async _ =>
            {
                async Task DisposeThing()
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Before Delay");
                    await Task.Delay(10000); // This would be the actual call to dispose the thing
                    Debug.WriteLine("After Delay");
                };
                await DisposeThing()
                .ContinueWith(async task => 
                {
                    if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
                        return; //you could notify the parent of this issue
                    await Self.GracefulStop(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                });
            });
        }
        protected override void PostStop()
        {            
            base.PostStop();
        }
        public static Props Prop()
        {
            return Props.Create(()=> new ChildActor());
        }

        public sealed class ShutDown
        {
            public static ShutDown Instance => new ShutDown();  
        }
    }
}
```

So instead of stopping the `_childActor` from the `parentActor` side you could send a `shutdown` message to the child to shutdown following the defined steps: first dispose the `non-akka thing` (to ensure it is truly not alive in-memory) afterwards, second, self-destruct the child which will notify the parent!

Comment: Thank you. What happens though if `ChildActor` is stopped via `PoisonPill`, `Context.Stop` or throws an unhandled exception, wouldn't all of that bypass the logic handled by the `ShutDown` handler?

Comment: The solution does not make use of `PoisonPill` nor `Context.Stop` - for your particular use case that will be problematic. You should probably not execute long running code within `PostStop`.

So to `Kill` the child actor and dispose the long running `non-akka thing` object, parent actor should send the child a `ShutDown` message.

Comment: I like your approach, but I'm looking for stronger guarantees and not assume that other actors will always play nice or that an unhandled exception won't occur.

Comment: You could always wrap your code within a `try...catch` block. I don't know what other thing the child actor does, your question was about ensuring `non-akka thing` is disposed!

Comment: For example, what happens if the parent (or a parent of that parent) dies due an unhandled exception, taking its child with it? I'm not sure you can force it to send a `Shutdown` message in all cases.

Comment: You have to guard against unhandled exceptions explicitly given your use case. If you want to intentionally kill the parent, you can send a `ShutDown` message to the child actor. You can also try sending `ShutDown` message from the parent `PostStop` method!